# Chrome basic authentication custom message stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, basic-authentication, ntlm

I am using nginx proxy to server my web-page. For login user need to provide his 2 factor authentication code and his password, to let users know that they need to enter their password+2 factor code to login, I send them a message "Login required, username, password+VIP token"'

And this what I get now [image]

This has stopped working from Chrome version 49. I am on 49.0.2623.110.

Any work around to fix this? It works perfectly on firefox.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This was indeed answered in [Change Basic HTTP Authentication realm and login dialog message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666306/change-basic-http-authentication-realm-and-login-dialog-message).

**Short explanation:** You were actually defining *realms* with [`auth_basic` directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) of Nginx on the *server* side. But "whether to prompt this message or not" is basically a design choice made by specific *client* programs. And Chrome just chose to hide it, for reasons you may find in the first link.

In fact, as of my decade (2022), Firefox seems to hide the message too.

---

**Why I necromance this *very* old post:** I was reading [this documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/) of Nginx. At the end of the article, there is a screenshot similar to the Firefox one in the OP. Unsurprisingly, my browser didn't behave like that even I followed all the instructions therein. Then I started Googling and this is the first hit relevant to my question. After I learned something about HTTP basic authentication, realm etc and finally came across the first link, I think I should post something here.

Apparently, Nginx documentation is using kinda modern UI to host kinda outdated contents. Hope this answer will help anyone who is confused by that screenshot too ;)