# Change Basic HTTP Authentication realm and login dialog message

Tags: http, go, http-headers, http-authentication

I want to change the message that pops up during implementation of Basic Auth.The current default message is:

[image]

> Server requires a username and password.

Something that would be more accurate for me is :

> Server requires an Email and Password.

My problem is that i can't find or don't know where this message is set and if it can be changed. Most of the questions online are about Basic Auth implemention but this is not my problem -- i can implement it very fine. I just need a more accurate response for the user.

Here is how i force an authentication window using echo:

```
c.Response().Header().Set(echo.HeaderWWWAuthenticate, `Basic realm="Your Email is your Username"`)
return echo.ErrUnauthorized
```

NB: Only Firefox shows the realm message. Both Chrome and Opera do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the responses but they were not satisfactory. I had to do some reading on this topic.

**The correct answer is that the login prompt/dialog is a response built into the user-agent/browser and cannot be changed by the server. This also explains why some browsers show realm while others don't.**

According to Wikipedia Basic access authentication all the server does is:

> When the server wants the user agent to authenticate itself towards the server, it must respond appropriately to unauthenticated requests.
>
> Unauthenticated requests should return a response whose header contains a HTTP 401 Unauthorized status[4] and a WWW-Authenticate field.[5]
>
> The WWW-Authenticate field for basic authentication (used most often) is constructed as following:
>
> WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm"

Answer (score 7):

This is not related to Go but actually to browser behaviour when receiving that header.

It seems Chrome/Chromium has a known issue with this related to the feature not considered secure by the development team, so I don't think you'd be able to fix it on your side unless you resort to some other authentication mechanism.

See here for more details:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544244#c32

Comment: Good to know. That answers the missing realm on some browsers. Do you know anything about changing the default message that appears on all browsers?

Comment: @Godfrey: the authentication dialog is created by the browser, you can't modify that from your code on the server.